# MBProgressHUD is not showing sometime in iOS

Tags: ios, json, mbprogresshud

I am using `MBProgressHUD` Custom Control to show when loading JSON Data from web.

I have already find a lot of answer that doesn't show correctly HUD Control in their View.

Here is my code to show `HUD` in my View.

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

and Here is how i hide my `HUD` View.

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

In ViewDidLoad , that control is working fine.

But when i click to refresh button and want to show HUD control , it doesn't show HUD Control.

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

dispatch_queue_t myqueue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(myqueue, ^{

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tbl reloadData];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Even though you do a bunch of dispatching, all your work is ending up on the main queue! That will block the UI and the HUD won't show.

Comment: So how do i need to edit my code?

Comment: Try calling fetchedData: directly instead of performing on the main thread and see if everything still works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Switch your code to this:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

dispatch_queue_t myqueue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(myqueue, ^{

    //Whatever is happening in the fetchedData method will now happen in the background
    [self fetchedData:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tbl reloadData];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

You don't want to call the `fetchData` method on the main thread. If you use the code above, nothing in the `fetchedData` method will happen on the main thread, so make sure you don't update the UI or anything in there.

Just a suggestion, I wouldn't use the name `"queue"` for your `dispatch_queue`. The names of the queues across the app need to be unique, so I'd call it something like `"your.bundle.id.viewcontrollername"` just to avoid issues later.